I cant see data in table 'Key' and in table 'Summary' (SQL)
The following SQL query works.

It counts all projects that are in G1 and G2. On the other screenshot you can see how the tables are displayed to me.

Unfortunately, nothing is shown to me in the "Key" and "Summary" tables. It would be great if the data was displayed there too, because the key and summary contain relevant data from the projects that simply come from a Kanban board. How to adapt my SQL statement so that it also displays the data in the key and summary.
I used the following SQL query:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Projekte', T1.'Milestone', T1.'Key', T1.'Summary'
FROM 
(SELECT
      CASE 
          WHEN T1.'Labels' LIKE "%G1%" THEN "G1"
          WHEN T1.'Labels' LIKE "%G2%" THEN "G2" 
      END AS Milestone
FROM T*) T
WHERE T.Milestone IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.Milestone

I tried the following:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Projects', T1.'Milestone', T1.'Key', T1.'Summary'
FROM 
(SELECT
      CASE 
          WHEN T1.'Labels' LIKE "%G1%" THEN "G1"
          WHEN T1.'Labels' LIKE "%G2%" THEN "G2" 
      END AS Milestone
FROM T*) T
WHERE T.Milestone IS NOT NULL AND T1.Key IS NOT NULL AND T1.Summary IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.Milestone

Unfortunately that doesn't work either...

Use correct quote symbols.

This doesn't look like Mysql and if it was mysql it would throw at least 2 errors (bad reference and single quotes around object names). Please clarify the platform in which you are writing this sql.
